# rename country name in text object

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

I have a qlikview file which have a text object that is showing countries the expression for text object that is fetching countries is

=[FIN-AP-Company Code Country Text]

now there are some countries in the source data that are not named correctly, now what should I do in qlikview file so that country name is renamed to proper name

```
Current Name                    Rename to 
Utd.Arab Emir.                  United Arab Emirates 
Bahráin                         Bahrain 
Rep.of                          Congo Republic of Congo 
Cote d'Ivoire                   Ivory Coast 
Camerún                         Cameroon 
Argelia                         Algeria 
Gabón                           Gabon 
Guinea Ecuatori                 Equatorial Guinea 
Jordania                        Jordan 
Níger                           Niger 
Omán                            Oman 
Sudáfrica                       South Africa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't do a reload, nest several "Replace" commands around the expression.

**Replace(s, fromstring ,tostring)**

Returns a string after replacing all occurrences of a given substring within the string s with another substring. The function is non-recursive and works from left to right.

*s* is the original string.

*fromstring* is a string which may occur one or more times within string.

*tostring* is the string which will replace all occurrences of fromstring within the string.

**Example:**
replace('abccde','cc','xyz') returns 'abxyzde'

Comment: thank you very much I tried with                                                                                                               =Replace(Replace(Replace([FIN-AP-Company Code Country Text],'Bahráin','Bahrain'),'Gabón','Gabon'),'Jordania','Jordan')     and looks like it is working the only one I am having trouble with is Cote d'Ivoire since it is having ' in the string I wonder if there is any skip symbol in qlikview

Comment: PurgeChar will remove substrings (or single quotes) from strings. Otherwise, have the search look for that escape character. https://community.qlik.com/blogs/qlikviewdesignblog/2015/06/08/escape-sequences

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ApplyMap()` function in the script to change the names.

```
CountryMapping:
Mapping
Load * Inline [
  OldName        , NewName
  Utd.Arab Emir. , United Arab Emirates 
  Bahráin        , Bahrain 
  Rep.of Congo   , Republic of Congo 
];
```

And then in the script part where the country field is loaded:

`ApplyMap('CountryMapping', [FIN-AP-Company Code Country Text] ) as [FIN-AP-Company Code Country Text]`

This will change the names only for the countries specified in the 'CountryMapping` table. All other values will remain as it is.

Comment: Thanks stefen for the response I can't load the file data again since the people who created the file are in another country ,all I can do at this moment is to change the expression code, I was wondering is there another way without loading the data

Comment: You can copy the current file under new name. Remove all the script. Make a binary load from the original file. Add the mapping table. Create new table by resident load from the table where the country field is but add the applymap in the country field (remember to use NoConcatenate function) and then drop the original table. I think that this is more safe way to do it and will not mess with the expression(s?). I can upload small qvw example if its not clear.